# Android SpannableStringBuilder add Editetxtview in Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have found the following code where i can add an image within a Textview with the help of SpannableStringBuilder. I would also like to add a EditText field within the textview, just like how image is added below. I'm struggling with this from a lot of time. Thanks in advance

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);    
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append("My string. I ")
                .append(" ", new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_heart), 0)
                .append(" Cree by Dexode");

textView.setText(builder);
```

[image]

As you can see in the Picture attached, image was successfully spanned within the textview. Similarly I would like to an EditText field within Textview

Answer (score 1):

You cannot attach another `View` inside a `View`. Remember that `ImageSpan` is not a `ImageView` but a `Bitmap` drawn inside `TextView` just like texts..

If you wish to let user input inside your view you Should use a `EditText` along `TextWatcher` or Simply Position a `EditText` over your `TextView`.